# Add and update values in session

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session, foreach

I'm Facing problem in adding variable or row from database into `$_SESSION`.
Here i'm fetch rows from database and storing it into $_SESSION with the help of array. But i'm not able to update/add/delete row quantity in `$_SESSION[]`.

I will be very  thankful if you tell me what is the proper way of adding arrays to `$_SESSION[]` and how to update/delete its particular row only in `$_SESSION[]`. When i use  `in_array()` it only finds the last row values. when i try to find values of 2nd or 3rd row it says not found.

Note : I have searched in stackoverflow for this question. but those answere not come close to my question. Here are those links below [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691109/add-and-update-row-in-database) ,[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954757/update-value-in-session-array-php), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453785/update-the-value-of-select-box-with-php-mysql-jquery-ajax?noredirect=1#comment72110887_42453785)

Here is my database table :

[image: Table Image]

my Output  :

[image: Output image]

PHP page :

```
 <?php
    $link = new mysqli('localhost','root','admin','pavancart');
    if ($link->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: ".$link->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM  product";
    $res= $link->query($sql);

    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
        $_SESSION['item']=$row;
        echo '<pre>';
            echo print_r ($_SESSION["item"],true);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    if(in_array("1",$_SESSION['item'])){
        echo "found";
    }else{
        echo "Not found";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is fine but $_SESSION['item'] is replaced by new row every time so, `in_array("1",$_SESSION['item'])` statement after the loop always looks in last item fetched by while loop. If you want to check in every row put `if ... else` statement inside while loop,

if you want to put all records in `$_SESSION['item']`, you could not accomplish like this, you should first declare `$_SESSION['item']` as an array then push each row in it... like-

```
// declare $_SESSION['item'] as an array
$_SESSION['item'] = [];
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    // Now push each row in $_SESSION['item']
    // ........... place your if ........ else block here
    array_push($_SESSION['item'],$row);
}

echo '<pre>';
// now you will get $_SESSION["item"] in 2D array
echo print_r ($_SESSION["item"],true);
echo "</pre>";
```

If you want to make search functionality over 2D array please [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value)

Comment: feel free to ask question related with this

Comment: @ Veshraj Joshi i'm very new to $_SESSION in php with your code i have acheived that i'm able to search through array. now i need to delete or update it.

Comment: now, to delete make use of `unset($_SESSION['item'][rownumber])`, to update you can simply assign -
  `$_SESSION['item'][rowindex]['rowindexFieldKey']='somevalue'`

Comment: let me know whether my last comment works for you or not